# Multi-valued field in Django

Tags: django

I can't believe this hasn't come up before but:

If I want my model to have one "primitive" field with multiple values, how would I go about declaring it? For example, multiple integers, strings, booleans or datetimes.

My initial thought would be to create a second model with my model's FK and one of the fields I mentioned:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass

class MyModelInteger(models.Model):
    integer = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

But (i) does this justify the use of a second table? (ii) How would I access the integer values directly from `MyModel`? I can't use the `through` option because that works for intermediate associated models, not with simple attributes.

I am probably overthinking this, but surprisingly enough I haven't come across this scenario as far as I memory goes, so I'd appreciate some help to clear it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, given the *order* of the integers does not matter here, and these numbers are "entities", you can do this.

You can fetch the items with:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    def my_integers():
        return self.mymodelinteger_set.values_list('value', flat=True)

class MyModelInteger(models.Model):
    integer = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

Here you thus query the `value` attributes of the *related* `MyModelInteger`s.

The above also is useful if you for example want to obtain all `MyModel` objects that have a related integer value that is for example `3`:

```
# obtain all MyModels with a related integer that is 3
MyModel.objects.filter(mymodelinteger__value=3)
```

The above can however be overkill if you just want to store some numbers in a model, and you do not have to filter on these numbers. In that case, you could for example use a [**`JSONField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField) (this is a specific one for PostgreSQL), or for non-PostgreSQL you can use [`django-jsonfield` [GitHub]](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield).

Here you thus can store vanilla Python objects as JSON in the database, this is typically a good idea for small amounts of data that can be dynamically structured, and where filters (well in case of PostgreSQL you *can* filter) is not necessary.

Then you can use it like:

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
# or for PostgreSQL
# from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    integers = JSONField(default=list)
```